# ns-renderer: localStorage is not defined

Tags: nativescript, angular2-seed

I am developing angular2seedadvanced app. The Web and Desktop app are created successfully but while building nativescript app it shows an error

> ns-renderer: localStorage is not defined

I am following [this plugin](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced).

And also loopback sdk builder and mongoDb.

I am new to nativescript. any help will highly helpfull and appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

`localStorage` does not exist in NativeScript. You need to use `application-settings` module instead.

Have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2517

Comment: I have nativescript sdk provided by loopback sdk builder. In that i have this application settings you mentioned above but i dont know how to include this only in nativecsript (angular2seedadvanced app) web and desktop app work perfectly but nativescript not.